# How can I resurface a masonry pool deck?

Tags: pool, repainting

The [Kool Deck](http://www.kooldeck.com/) around our pool in Arizona is faded & chipped in a few small places, and since we painted the house, it is really the wrong color.  Is there a way to re-color the Kool Deck surface that still would maintain the "cool" property of the surface?  (Dunn-Edwards said their paint would result in loss of the cooling property & be hotter to walk on.)

Answer (score 3):

The original Kool Deck is a proprietary concrete/limestone surface treatment for  concrete surfaces. The porous properties of the limestone in the mix allow the coating to take maximum advantage of natural evaporative cooling (the assumption being that the pool deck is usually damp/wet). When not wet, the "knock down" texture of the coating reduces skin to surface contact area so will *feel* cooler whether or not the surface temperature is actually cooler.

Any paint coating over this surface is likely to negatively affect the evaporative cooling properties. To truly retain the properties you have (if you truly have "Kool Deck"") and change colors, means removing the surface coating and reapplying  the same or similar surface treatment.

[This guy](https://jeffmmoreau.wordpress.com/tag/textured-pool-deck-coating/) claims to have a product that does what you want, but I could never endorse it without a real world test. You could look into it though.